# Установка pip3 на Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

У меня есть vps на Ubuntu 12.04. По умолчанию стоит python 2.7.3, но мне нужен python 3 и соответствующий pip.

Пробовал делать как предлагают здесь, например: https://askubuntu.com/a/412179

Но после такой установки у меня вываливается ошибка как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517872/pip3-version-failing-with-a-syntaxerror

Вопрос: неужели нет возможности поставить pip3 без танцев с бубнами? И как это сделать хотя бы с танцами..? Потому что у меня так ничего и не получилось

Comment: «И как это сделать хотя бы с танцами» — поставить Ubuntu 17.04? :)

Comment: Так это ж виртуальный сервер

Comment: И что? На vps можно установить любую ОС

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов уйма. Например, установить https://github.com/saghul/pythonz и с помощью него установить столько версий Питона, сколько нужно. Если при этом не будет установлен и соотв. `pip`, то проще всего скачать https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py (соотв версии) и запустить его ТЕМ ИНТЕРПРЕТАТОРОМ (с полным путем до него), для которого ты ставишь `pip`. Если стоит `easy_install` - им также можно установить `pip`. Кроме того можно инсталлировать `virtualenv` и он тебе установит сам и соотв `pip` и `easy_install`

Comment: Кстати. Есть еще способ. Все так же за искл того, что вместо pythonz установить Питон из исходников при помощи `make altinstall`